# effects of overriding stderr in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

The following code made python crash:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = None
print "goodbye world!"
```

I know there is no real reason to write such code but I was wondering why it's crashing.
my first guess was that the `print` command fails because `stdout` is overridden and then, while trying to raise an exception, another exception is raised because `stderr` is overridden too.

So it gets a stack overflow while trying to raise an exception.

Can anyone explain what is really happening in the background here?
Is this a stack overflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `print` statement throws an exception because `sys.stdout` is set to `None`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout = None
>>> print "goodbye world!"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

This exception alone is enough for Python to exit as you are not handling the exception anywhere.

However, you set `sys.stderr` to `None` *as well*, so there is nowhere for this traceback to be written to. This situation is special-cased in the [`PyErr_Display` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/465d81c1b2fc/Python/pythonrun.c#l1220):

```
PyObject *f = PySys_GetObject("stderr");
Py_INCREF(value);
if (f == NULL || f == Py_None)
    fprintf(stderr, "lost sys.stderr\n");
```

Here Python writes a message to the original `stderr` (the one handed to Python by the OS, not `sys.stderr`) to let you know it could not tell you what really went wrong.

This is **not** a crash, this is Python handling the situation gracefully.